# How to run a python script in bash, and use the output for cd?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to do:

`alias go=cd $(go.py $1)`

then run

`?> go home`

`go.py` prints some directory (/my/special/home), which is used by cd to go to that location.  But, it doesn't work. If I change the alias to:

`alias go=cd $(go.py home)`

it works fine, but I want it to be a bit more configurable. Something with the syntax I don't understand I assume.

Comment: I think your first deal is going to literally spit out, if you type "go home", `cd $(go.py $1) home`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function instead of an alias:

```
function go() {
    cd "$(go.py "${1}")"
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but didn't use the curly braces for the argument. If you know, how does bash parse those?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter here. You could also use `"$1"`. The curly braces are good when you use variable names like `${FOO_BAR}`. If you would use `$FOO_BAR` it is unclear if the variable is called `FOO_BAR` or if you expand the variable `FOO` and append the string `_BAR`. That's why it is a good habit to use curly braces.